# New hardware - system does not boot anymore - how to reset systemd/udev?

Tags: boot, networking, udev, systemd

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I just replaced the hardware (new motherboard, new CPU, new GPU, new RAM, new network card, new SATA controller) and now Ubuntu doesn't boot up anymore. After a while, I get into the emergency shell and it seems I have full access to the system there. I was able to manually setup the network (`ifconfig en5ps0 up; dhclient en5ps0` <- very strange interface name it came up with). When looking at the journal (`journalctl -xb`), it seems like it got a timeout while waiting for some disk it does not find anymore.

Some maybe relevant journal messages:

```
...
systemd: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 2816 (plymouthd).
...
root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
...
root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/samba returned non-zero exit status 1
...
systemd: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID 3100 (plymouthd).
...
systemd: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-....device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-...device/start timed out.
systemd: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-....device.
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by...device has failed
...
-- The result is timeout.
systemd: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/....
...
systemd: Dependency failed for /mnt/....
...
systemd: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
...
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
root@gcomputer:~# cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0

#/dev/sdb1: UUID="56fc92d2-1903-4263-b88e-d09bc15ef1d3" TYPE="ext4"
#/dev/sdb2: UUID="f9b799de-c564-4e00-9924-4e8a0ffe8d51" TYPE="swap"

# new SSD (OCZ-VERTEX2_OCZ-K5Q40019666QDZLM)
UUID=56fc92d2-1903-4263-b88e-d09bc15ef1d3 /               ext4    discard,noatime,user_xattr,acl,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /dev/sdb5:
# UUID=78ca7a27-6fcc-493c-a10a-5ed961a682e5 none            swap    discard,sw              0       0


/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

# very old Gentoo (ST380011A_5JVHHAX0)
UUID=64f30a2f-1c38-40e8-8ab2-7f639b9c3673   /mnt/gentooroot reiserfs    user_xattr,acl  0 1
UUID=a448006c-43df-4fbe-be3d-18da22b4e29c   /mnt/gentooroot/home    reiserfs    user_xattr,acl  0 1

# oldroot (WDC_WD5000AACS-00G8B1_WD-WCAUK0065639)
UUID=2474adbe-ca12-4ad1-bea1-1938fdb1c8a4   /mnt/oldroot            ext3    noatime,user_xattr,acl,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

`blkid`:

```
root@gcomputer:~# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="56fc92d2-1903-4263-b88e-d09bc15ef1d3" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="2db0af09-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="f9b799de-c564-4e00-9924-4e8a0ffe8d51" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2db0af09-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2474adbe-ca12-4ad1-bea1-1938fdb1c8a4" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="00039d20-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="78ca7a27-6fcc-493c-a10a-5ed961a682e5" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="00039d20-05"
```

So, how do I fix this? Why does it even wait for the disk? The root filesystem including home and everything which it needs is already available.

Do I need to tell udev or systemd or whatever to rescan for new hardware or for new disk ids or so? Why doesn't it do that automatically?

How would I debug that further?

Answer (score 5):

1. **Match UUID's**...

In `terminal`...

- `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak` # make a backup
- `sudo blkid`
- `sudo cat /etc/fstab`

For every line output from blkid, compare it to any uncommented line in /etc/fstab, and assure that the UUIDs match the respective /dev/sdxx.

2. **Two swap partitions, and no swap definition in /etc/fstab**...

Both sda2 and sdb5 are swap partitions. You only need one. Delete /dev/sda2 and uncomment the sdb5 line in /etc/fstab with `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

3. **Unused disks**...

Comment out the lines shown below, with `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`...

any NTFS mounts

/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

UUID=64f30a2f-1c38-40e8-8ab2-7f639b9c3673   /mnt/gentooroot reiserfs    user_xattr,acl  0 1

UUID=a448006c-43df-4fbe-be3d-18da22b4e29c   /mnt/gentooroot/home    reiserfs    user_xattr,acl  0 1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/597551)

Comment: I suggested that he edit his fstab, that's exactly what he did, and it works now. How isn't that an answer to the question?

Comment: you save my day. I wasted for 5 hours due to it in my holiday. :'''(

Answer (score 0):

After deleting some entries from my `/etc/fstab`, this seems to have fixed some of the problems. I still wonder why it failed to boot because of that, also about the other errors, and I still don't get a graphical login (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804947/systemctl-graphic-login-did-not-show-up-why)) but maybe at least this first problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to previous answers.

Instead of commenting out parts of fstab, change their options. Do you really need to have mounted NTFS/FAT drive/partition during boot, or you using these occasionally? If latter, you should add "noauto" option into options section of mount definition line.

For example. Was:

```
LABEL="NTFS drive" /media/NTFSD NTFS some_options
```

If partition with label "NTFS Drive" is absent, or something wrong with it, you may avoid the problems:

```
LABEL="NTFS drive" /media/NTFSD NTFS noauto,some_options
```

Then the system will not try to mount this on boot...