# Using startx to begin admin Xsession from terminal?

Tags: ssh, xorg, login, dpkg

I want to be able to start an admin-level Xsession over SSH if I need to VNC in. Running `startx` using `sudo` works as I want it to, but is an obvious no-no as it switches the ownership of the `.Xauthority` file in the user's `home` directory to root.

Running without `sudo` is denied.

There apparently used to be a way to change some settings in `Xwrapper.config` either directly or using `dpkg`, but that seems to be redundant - there are no equivalents in `Xsession.options` and trying to use `dpkg` to reconfigure `x11-common` results in this warning:

```
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

and nothing else.

Someone else asked the [same question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804957/startx-as-a-user-fails) a few months ago, and the only supplied answer suggested using `dpkg`, which won't work.

Everything else I've found is years old and very out of date. Surely it can't be that difficult?

*Edit:* Tried installing xserver-xorg-legacy and changing the settings in there with `dpkg` to allow anyone to start the X server. The settings do something - if I change it to 'console only' I'll get a warning trying to run xinit, but if I change it back to 'anybody' I get the usual `Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)` error.

Comment: `startx` over `ssh` should not work to my knowledge. You should better go on with VNC, if you really need whole X session (why?).

Comment: I say right there in the post I am wanting to VNC in. 

I want to be able to start an X session for a particular user from the terminal and then VNC in to that. Again, as I said, it's entirely possible already using sudo - this works exactly as I want it to except for the fact it changes my user account's .Xsession ownership to root so I need to change it back every time I log out of X. I could write a bash script to do it, but that seems like using a hammer to crack a nut - the capability apparently used to be there.

Comment: Take a look at bug 1562219 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xinit/+bug/1562219  . Seems pretty closely related, add yourself to the list if appropriate.

Comment: Do me a favour and paste that in as an answer so I can upvote you for it and it gets better visibility - that is very definitely the same rabbit hole I'm down.